# How To Update a PHP Array In Another File Easily

Tags: php, arrays

so I have a confg.php file which contains config details like this:

```
$CONFIG = Array (
'APIKey' => 'xxxxxx',
'USERNAME' => 'admin',
'PASSWORD' => 'password',
);
```

I want users to be able to update these credentials through admin.php but I am quite not sure how I can update an array through another file so please help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're approaching this wrong. I would suggest you create a database table called config and have in here columns for APIKey, USERNAME and PASSWORD. Within your admin.php you can allow the user to update these records ..

```
update settings_table set APIKEY='a', USERNAME='b', PASSWORD='c' where id=1
```

And then on your front end you can query this table to get the values ..

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from settings_table where id=1", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);

$CONFIG = Array (
   'APIKey' => $row['APIKey'],
   'USERNAME' => $row['USERNAME'],
   'PASSWORD' => $row['PASSWORD'],
);
```

EDIT: You don't want to use MySQL

OK, you could do this with a file that stores the config settings. You should put this into a non-web accessible directory.

So, in your admin.php file you can write the details to a file:

```
$myFile = "/full/path/to/config.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_POST['APIKey'] . "\n";
$stringData = $_POST['USERNAME'] . "\n";
$stringData = $_POST['PASSWORD'] . "\n";
fclose($fh);
```

And then on your front end you can open the file, split up the rows and then build your $CONFIG array:

```
$data = file_get_contents("/full/path/to/config.txt");
$data = explode("\n", $data);

$CONFIG = Array (
   'APIKey' => $data[0],
   'USERNAME' => $data[1],
   'PASSWORD' => $data[2],
);
```

Comment: Actually I am making a minimal script that's why I was chasing a way to do Flat File Database and not run MySQL queries, I know how to use MySQL but this project is different and a challenge to me personally. Thanks though.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer to give a non-MYSQL approach. Good luck

Comment: Thanks Chris, I hope this would help some people out but right now I have found a better alternative to my problem and that is a FlatDB.php class I found from a GitHub user and it's pretty useful. Thanks again!