# Changing PHP Array Values In Another PHP File

Tags: php, arrays, configuration

I am willing to update an array which is saved in another file. I know how to read PHP Arrays from another file but how do I update them?

This is my array saved in config.php:

```
$CONFIG = Array (
'APIKey' => 'xxx-xxx-xxx',
'USERNAME' => 'admin',
'PASSWORD' => 'password',
);
```

I want to update this from admin.php file and save them like a config file. I have tried using ini files but they are easily accessible and can't store sensitive data practically on a web application.

**UPDATE:** For People who are saying this is like the other question, it's not. Answer to that question is for Arrays which has items with no particular name like 'PASSWORD' and it just uses '$CONFIG[0]' or things like that. Though I kept that question and answer as it is because it can help out other people while I am looking for a better solution to it.

Please help me out, thanks!

Comment: Tell us - what is the difference with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42932471/how-to-update-a-php-array-in-another-file-easily?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Update a PHP Array In Another File Easily](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42932471/how-to-update-a-php-array-in-another-file-easily)

Comment: I have reposted this question because the other question didn't make much sense and the answer to it wasn't applicable to my case. I am looking for a possible different solution as I know there are more ways to do it but I just can't seem to find them.

Comment: Then explain what have you tried and what is not working, otherwise it can be considered as a duplicate.